# Next 24 hour Time

Tags: magento2, php

I am working on magento2 i want date of next day from current date.

Comment: Do u think is it possible to have records with created_at  greater then current time ??

Comment: see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$currentDateTime = new \DateTime();
$currentDateTime->modify("+1 day");
$dateTime = $currentDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```